# Layouts inside layouts

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to figure out how can I make an app with Kivy.
A calendar made of buttons but with multiple layouts so I can organize everything to my liking.
All of this is quite new to me and I can't figure out how to make layouts properly. In some videos, the def build(self) returns a layout or a widget or a label, what if I want to return multiple layouts? Do I need to create those layouts inside the Main layout so all of them appear? What if I want to create my calendar made of buttons but since a month has different days, I need to create it inside the .py file and not the .kv, but what if I want to mess around with the same FloatLayout which has my calendar buttons, inside the .kv file and organize it with multiple Layouts for other stuff?
I don't if I'm being clear about my problem.

I've watched several videos, but they are really simplified.

## main.py

```py
import kivy
import calendar

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class CustomFloat(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(CustomFloat,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 7
        self.size_hint_y = 0.3
        self.size_hint_x = 0.9
        self.pos_hint = {"top": 0.9, "x": 0.05}
        self.c  = calendar.monthcalendar(2015,5)
        for i in self.c:
            for j in i:
                if j == 0:
                    self.add_widget(Button(text = '{j}'.format(j='')))
                else:
                    self.add_widget(Button(text = '{j}'.format(j=j)))

        def on_release(self):
            pass

class FloatingApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return CustomFloat()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FloatingApp().run()
```

my code is what I've wanted to do (a calendar made of buttons), but I want that layout inside a bigger layout so I can make multiple layouts for each day tasks, or for buttons from which I can change the month, etc, etc..
and if someone knows how to link a Layout made on main.py to a layout in .kv file (so I can tweak inside .kv and/or organize it) please let me know.

EDIT: if I create another Layout but this time on .kv file, it takes a size of a button and puts himself inside the layout I created in main.py.. why?

Comment: A layout is also just a widget, you can just use `layout1.add_widget(layout2)`.

Comment: If you want your `CustomFloat` inside a bigger `Layout`, then just put it in a bigger `Layout` as @syntonym points out (`bigger_layout.add_widget(CustomFloat()`). Then your `build` method should return the bigger `Layout`. You should post a [mcve] in order to get the best answers.